# what is the default time out of HttpTransportSE?

Tags: android

I use http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/ library and I want to know 
What is the default time out of HttpTransportSE ? 
when initiating it with

```
HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(WebServiceURL);
```

Answer (score 2):

For the record: according to the [GitHub source file ServiceConnection (line34)](https://github.com/mosabua/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-base/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/transport/ServiceConnection.java#L34), the default timeout used in the class Transport - which is the base class for HttpTransport and HttpTransportSE - is 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

From the [tips section](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks) of the code you can set your own time out by adding more arguments to the method you call

```
 HttpsTransportSE transport = new HttpsTransportSE(host, port, file, timeout);
```

Where the timeout is an int.

Comment: I want to know the value of default timeout when you don't use it in your constructor like HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(WebServiceURL);

Comment: i have with 120 seconds(120000) in HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, WS_Timeout_Limit);in soap xml req.but, some time, server responding within 15 seconds.but, mobile will timeout within ten seconds. but, i dont know why Nick..can u help me.